# Htaccess Rule to Ignore File Extensions (Eg. ".htm")

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, .htaccess

I am using Zend Framework and want to be able to end my URLs in ".htm". What should I add to my .htaccess file?

So the following would be equivilent:

*www.mysite.com/controller

www.mysite.com/controller.htm*

As would:

*www.mysite.com/controller/action

www.mysite.com/controller/action.htm*

Nothing I have tried seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is [mod_rewrite](http://www.modrewrite.com/). Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)\.htm$ $1
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

You could use this rule to remove the `.htm` ending:

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.htm$ $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this with `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` - it lets me apply regex before the request is routed to any particular controller. Nice because I can then keep my default ZF .htaccess file and not have my logic spread about too much.